# How do i write the following query in php Yii2?

Tags: mysql, yii2

select print_date as pdate ,
count(print_date) as pcount
from cards
where print_date BETWEEN  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY) and CURRENT_DATE()
group by print_date

*********with one more condition where created_by=>Yii::$app->user->identity;

Comment: We won't write code for you. Show your efforts. [How to Write Query in Yii2](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-query-builder)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['print_date AS pdate','count(print_date) as pcount'])
        ->from('cards')
        ->andwhere(['between','print_date','2021-03-01','CURRENT_DATE()'])
        ->andWhere(['created_by'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
        ->groupBy('print_date')
        ->all();
```

When i execute the above query i get the results but when i replace 2021-03-01 with DATE_SUB('CURRENT_DATE()',INTERVAL 7 DAYS) i get an empty  array[0]

```
    $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['print_date AS pdate','count(print_date) as pcount'])
        ->from('cards')
        ->andwhere(['between','print_date','DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 DAY)','CURRENT_DATE()'])
        ->andWhere(['created_by'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id])
        ->groupBy('print_date')
        ->all();
```